# Meaning of orthogonal vectors

Tags: vectors

What does it mean when the question says vector $a$ is 'orthogonal' to vector $b$ and $c$?

Also what does that mean when $a=b \times c$ in 3 dimension?

The questions says $b = (b_1, b_2, b_3)$ and $c=(c_1, c_2, c_3)$

and $a=b \times c$ , so $a=(b_2c_3-c_2b_3, c_1b_3-b_1c_3, b_1c_2-b_2c_2)$

and this vector $a$ is 'orthogonal to both vector $b$ and vector $c$.

What does this mean??

Comment: Looks like $a$,$b$ and $c$ are vectors and not matrices ...

Comment: Then what does orthogonal vector mean? I don't understand the 'orthogonal' here...

Comment: Why would I ask here if I could understand from there?

Comment: Usually, for vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$, a vector $a$ is said to be orthogonal to another vector $b$ if their dot product $a \cdot b$ is zero. Since $a \cdot b = b \cdot a$ (i.e. the dot product is commutative), it doesn't matter if we say "$a$ is orthogonal to $b$" or "$b$ is orthogonal to $a$", and sometimes people may also simply say "$a$ and $b$ are orthogonal (to each other)". Also, the dot product is a kind of *inner product*, which is a generalization of the dot product, and you might come across the following definition: two vectors are orthogonal if their inner product is zero.

Comment: Do you know the right-hand rule? That's what we're talking about if $a=b\times c$ is concerned. I recommend reading the wikipedia article about the cross product. Hope I could help :)

Comment: $b \times c$ is the *cross product* of $b$ and $c$. The cross product takes two vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and gives you another vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$. The resulting vector $a = b \times c$ is orthogonal to both $b$ and $c$; this is a property of the cross product. You can verify this property by computing the dot products $a \cdot b$ and $a \cdot c$, and you will see that they are $0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In $R^2$ or $R^3$, two vectors are "orthogonal" if and only if they are **perpendicular**.  "Orthogonal"  means perpendicular.

In more abstract vector spaces, in order to talk about "orthogonal" you have to have an "inner product".  In an inner product space two vectors are "orthogonal" if and only if their inner product is 0.